# LaTeX formulas do not work with IE9

Tags: support, math-display

For some reason the LaTeX formulas do not work with IE9. On the top of the page I get a red bar saying "Statistical Analysis Meta works best with JavaScript enabled". I have not disabled javascript so I guess the MathJax is not comptabile with IE9. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

That message should only appear if javascript is disabled (it is enclosed in `<noscript>` tags). To confirm this try the following steps:

1. Load the page that shows the message
2. Go to the address bar in that same page
3. Type `javascript:alert("hi")`

If this displays an alert message with contents `hi` then javascript is enabled, otherwise disabled.

A couple of ideas:

- Reset the browser (Tools->Internet Options->Advanced->Reset Browser settings)
- Do you have any IE9 add-ons? They might be turning off scripting for certain pages

Comment: I tried IE9 again and today I see formulas with no problem! The red error bar is also gone. I didn't change anything in IE9. However, "tracking protection" is on and I'm subscribed to the easy list. I suspect that there was a false positive in the easy list and is fixed.